# Prove : Matrix is orthogonal after transformation

Tags: transformation, orthogonal-matrices

I need your help to prove the statement below, i tried several ways with out success.
I apologize for the bad translation, I hope it is clear :

Let B be NxN matrix which transforms **orthonormal** base `u1,u2,......un` to other **orthonormal** base `v1,v2,.....vn.`

(It means that for all `1 ≤  i < n` , exists Bui = vi)

According to this statement I want to prove that B is **orthogonal** Matrix.

Comment: Do you know how to express the columns of B in terms of $u_1, ..., u_n$, $v_1, ..., v_n$ ?

Comment: Not so sure, do you mean as Linear combination?

Comment: We need to know the definition of orthogonal matrix you are working with in order to help you.

Comment: B\*B = BB\* = I   ,  <Au,Av> = <u,v>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being an orthonormal base $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ means spanning $\mathbb{R}^n$ and satisfying $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$. We want to show that $B$ is orthogonal, that means that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we want to show that $\langle Bx, By\rangle=\langle x,y \rangle$. First of all write $x,y$ in terms of the orthonormal basis $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$:
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iu_i, \, y=\sum_{j=1}^n d_j u_j $$
where $c_i,d_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i,j=1,\dotso,n$. Now observe:

$$\langle Bx,By\rangle=\langle B(\sum_{i=1}^nc_iu_i),B(\sum_{j=1}^nd_ju_j)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nc_id_j\langle Bu_i,Bu_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nc_id_j\langle v_i,v_j\rangle= \\\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nc_id_j\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=\langle\sum_{i=1}^nc_iu_i,\sum_{j=1}^nd_ju_j\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle $$

Comment: Try to figure out what I did at every step in the equation to check wether you got it...

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! , it is not so clear to me , where is the transformation expressed here?

Comment: What do you mean by "transformation expressed"? The $B$ is defined by $B(u_i)=v_i$.

Answer (score 0):

"$Bu_i=v_i$ for all $i$" can be written under the compact form:

$$\tag{0}BU=V$$

where $U$ (resp. $V$) is the matrix whose columns are the $u_i$s (resp. the $v_i$s).

A matrix $M$ whose columns constitute an orthonormal basis is orthogonal (see explanation in the remark below)

Thus, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, and, as the set of orthogonal matrices forms a group (the orthogonal group), $(1)$, written under the form:

$$B=VU^{-1}$$

is meaningful and proves that $B$ is orthogonal.

Remark: the fact that an orthogonal matrix is characterized by the fact that its columns constitute an orthonormal basis is equivalent to the defining property of an orthonormal matrix, i.e.,

$$\tag{1}M^TM=I.$$

Proof: Let us consider the LHS of $(1)$; its generic element $a_{ij}$ is the product of line $L_i$ of $M^T$ with column $C_j$ of $M$, otherwise said, as the dot product of column $C_i$ with column $C_j$ of $M$. This dot product is $0$ if $i \neq j$, and $1$ in the case  $i=j$ ; we have found back, in this way matrix $I$, ther RHS of $(1).$

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful to the OP. First of all we don't know wether he knows the concept of a group. Additionally we don't know the definition of orthogonal matrix the OP has in mind...

Comment: Thanks for reply , to be honest I didn't understand this answer. I hope there is an alternative.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to do my best by adding some elements explaning the connection between different definitions/poperties of orthogonal matrices. The fact that the set or orthogonal matrices is a group is not important in itself. It suffices to say that the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is itself orthogonal and the product of two of them is still orthogonal.

Comment: May I asl you where you are blocked in my answer ?

Comment: There are several things I am not familiar with , but of course this has nothing to do with your answer. I appriciate your detailed answer and sure it might help someone else! Thank you.